# Thread Local Storage Not supported for this Architecture ios

Tags: ios, multithreading, thread-local, log4cplus

i am Compiling log4cplus Library for armv7, it Gives me Error

> Thread Local Storage is Not Supported for Current Device(__thread is Not Supported)

i have Searched this EveryWhere But Not Getting Exact Answer. i have Two Doubts Regarding TLS on ios:

- is it so that Apple is Not Supporting TLS?
- Do we Have Any Stariaght Forward Flag By Which we Can Set Flag for TLS?

**Compilation Details:**

- Compiled using Apple LLVM 6.1 Compiler
- i had used https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus/tree/master/iOS/scripts to build log4cplus Library

Answer (score 1):

- Need To Update Script File By **-DLOG4CPLUS_SINGLE_THREADED="FALSE"** for Multi Threading.